# Mypy: use higher (personal) type

Tags: python, annotations, mypy, type-hinting

I recently discovered mypy and I want my code to be type checked with it.

I have a `Something` base class:

```
class Something():
    ... something...
```

And I have several subclasses, they are all instances of `Something`, but of different types:

```
class Thing(Something)
    def __init__():
        short_name = "S"


class OtherThing(Something)
    def __init__():
        short_name = "T"
```

When I use these objects, I normally put them in a list:

```
s1 = Thing()
s2 = OtherThing()
list_things: List[Something] = list()
list_things.append(s1)
list_things.append(s2)
```

But apparently I can't do that, mypy doesn't recognize Thing and OtherThing as being "lower types" of Something.

How should I correct that?

Comment: Mypy actually typechecks the code that you provided without a problem. You should edit your post and make sure your example actually demonstrates the issue you're running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2984)

As can be seen there, and [in the official docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types), it is as designed

And as a workaround, quoting from [JukkaL's comment on github](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2984#issuecomment-285716826):

> You can often use `Sequence[x]` instead of `List[x]` to get code like your example working. This works because `Sequence` is covariant and doesn't let you set items in the list, unlike `List[x]` which is invariant and allows the mutation of the list.

Comment: The comment also says: "If your function doesn't actually modify the list, you can get around this error by typing the argument as Sequence[Base] or even Iterable[Base] instead.". Mine does modify the list.

Comment: I see. maybe try to avoid modifying the list then. I'm not affiliated with `mypy` but as I can see you don't have any other choice